# Spinner with multiple colors

Tags: android, kotlin

I have managed to change the spinner text and background color using the code below.

spinner_layout.xml layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"/>
```

kt file calling the above

```
ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.spinner_layout, companyList)
```

The above creates a black background with white text when the spinner is open but on close, my text is black on black as my layout background is black too. How do I change the spinner close state text to white?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4647702/5933012

Comment: I'm new and all of this is old code and in Java not Kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have different layout on open and on close by using this.

```
 adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.your_layout_resource_xml)
```

Of course before you have to create custom adapter, but i guess you already did that.

To have best result about the background, are need more changes:

[how can i change spinner background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43255262/how-can-i-change-spinner-background-color/43255417#43255417)

Basically you create custom layout for spinner and spinner items with two different layout

```
  <style name="AppTheme.spinnerStyle" 
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Spinner"> 

     <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
     <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>

  </style> 
  <style name="AppTheme.spinnerDropDownItemStyle" 
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner">

    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item> 
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your spinner like this

```
 <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:minHeight="45dp"
                android:padding="3dp">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/girth"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                     />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

And your spinner item view layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"/>
```

And in your onItemeSelectedListener change selected text color like this

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
    ((TextView)view).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
    // your code here
}
```

});

Comment: This is what I already have. I want the spinner closed to be: white text on back and when the spinner is open black text on white.

Comment: do you want your selected item text color to be in white color with black background?

Comment: Yes and before you make a selection. When you arrive on the form, the background is black and white text. When you open spinner, black text on white.

Comment: I have change my answer please check now , It will work